# Let $S\in \mathcal{L} (V, W)$. Proof of $[S^*]_{\beta^*}^{\gamma^*} = ([S]_\gamma^\beta)^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transpose, dual-spaces

If $V, W$ are vector spaces with bases $\beta, \gamma$ respectively, let $\beta^*, \gamma^*$ be dual bases.

Suppose $S \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$. 
Then the dual map of $S$, $S^* \in \mathcal{L}(W^*, V^*)$, is defined
$$
    S^*: W^* \to V^*; \quad \phi \mapsto \phi S.
    $$
This is my first exposure to dual maps, and I am completely stuck on the theorem that states
$[S^*]_{\beta^*}^{\gamma^*} = ([S]_\gamma^\beta)^T$.

I would be glad to post my attempts so far, but they are a mess so I will just outline my strategy.

First I would let $\beta = \{ \mathrm{v_1}, ..., \mathrm{v_n} \}$ and 
$\gamma = \{ \mathrm{w_1}, ..., \mathrm{w_m} \}$.

As I understand it, the dual bases of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are defined as
$\beta^* = \{ \varphi_1, ..., \varphi_n \}$ and 
$\gamma^* = \{ \pi_1, ... \pi_m \}$ where
$$
    \varphi_j(\mathbf{v_i}) =
    \begin{cases}
        1, & i = j\\ 0, & i \neq j
        \end{cases}
    $$
and
$$
    \pi_j(\mathbf{w_i}) =
    \begin{cases}
        1, & i = j\\ 0, & i \neq j
        \end{cases}.
    $$

So next, I suppose $$S(\mathbf{v_j}) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}{a_{ij} \mathbf{w_i}}$$ so that I can construct $[S]_\beta^\gamma$.

It turns out $([S]_\beta^\gamma)^T$ is the following matrix.
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{21} & \cdots & a_{m1}\\
        a_{12} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{m2}\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
        a_{1n} & a_{2n} & \cdots & a_{mn}
        \end{bmatrix}
    $$

Now the part I have trouble with is how to begin forming $[S^*]_{\gamma^*}^{\beta^*}$ and showing it is the same matrix as above.

I know that 
$[S^*]_{\gamma^*}^{\beta^*} = \left[ [S^*(\pi_1)]^{\beta^*} ... [S^*(\pi_m)]^{\beta^*} \right]$ but I have no idea how to express, say, 
$S^*(\pi_j)$ in terms of transformations in $\beta^*$.

So I am completely stuck. If someone could shed light on how this works, it would be much appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: I'm used to calling the elements of a dual basis $v_1^*,\cdots,v_m^*$. Writing the coordinates of a functional in this basis is rather simple: start by verifying that $$f=f(v_1)v_1^*+\cdots +f(v_m)v_m^*$$ And recall that $S^*(f):=f\circ S$.

Comment: Sorry, but how are $v_1^*, ..., v_m^*$ defined in this case? Is this a dual basis for $\gamma$? And what is $f$ in this case?